# Accept Request Payload in PHP

Tags: php

I need to accept Request Payload on my server, I do it like this:

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

I would like to understand if only Request Payload is always stored here, or if some other data can be stored here.

How can I check that The Request Payload data was received, and not something else?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you have? Reading `php://input` is correct, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input

Comment: @Progman, No problem. I want to be sure that php://data will definitely receive a Request Payload, and not something else

Comment: Anything that comes in that way will be some sort of payload. Are you asking how to validate that it contains something you actually want? To know that, we'd have to know what you consider to be valid data for this request

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $payloads = file_get_contents('php://input');
    var_dump($payloads); //you can see what is inside it
?>
```

Comment: I think the author of the question is looking for a way to verify it within the program not to dump it out for manual visual inspection.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.